# password protection

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts2

In an web application there are 2 users Admin and client.

Admin can create a client. Admin can give a password to client , later client can modify it.

if there need to be change in any information of client Admin will take the responsibility of editing details.
In our web application I made such a way that, when ever any information of client changed the password must be changed compulsorily and Admin must intimate client on changed password.
but, admin dont know his previous password.

Is this approach fine?

Comment: Sounds very restrictive to me.

Comment: is it not like forcing client to do something which he/she don't want every time?

Answer (score 0):

It's fine, but irritating for the user. (There are circumstances I could see this being okay, I suppose, but... not really.)

There's no reason for the admin to know the user's previous password--since they're an admin, and can make arbitrary changes to the user, as long as access to admin accounts is pretty secure.